# Solve recurrence relation $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How do I solve a recurrence relation like $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{n}$?

I have tried using generating function, got till the differential equation:

$f(x) - \int f(x)dx - \int xf(x)dx=a_0+a_1x-a_0x$ or after differentiation

$y^{'}-(1+x)y=c$

Comment: It would be polite to give us the differential equation you derived and the work you did so we don't have to re-derive it.

Comment: I was not sure about my working, so, decided not to include it, but I got the following equation: $f(x) - \int f(x)dx - \int xf(x)dx=a_0+a_1x-a_0x$

Comment: I think you sholuld insert that in the question instead of making a comment. Your question may be deleted soon if that is not done.

Comment: So differentiating, if $y = f(x)$ then $y' - (1+x) y = a_1 - a_0$.  You should be able to solve that with an integrating factor of $e^{-x-x^2/2}$ -- although if $a_1 \ne a_0$, then there will be an error function involved.  And even if $a_1 = a_0$, I'm not aware of any nice closed form for the series expansion of $e^{x+x^2/2}$.

Comment: You may find OEIS sequences to have good information. Try the sequences [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085), [A000932](https://oeis.org/A000932), [A059480](https://oeis.org/A059480), [A122031](http://oeis.org/A122031).

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, then (formally speaking, i.e. where it converges, which is obviously at least for $|x|<1$) $$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1} = a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})x^{n-1} = a_1 + (f(x)-a_0) + xf(x).$$ Thus $$f'(x) =  c + (x+1)f(x).$$
This implies that $$[f'(x)-(x+1)f(x)]e^{-\frac12(x+1)^2} = ce^{-\frac12(x+1)^2} \implies \frac d{dx} \Big(f(x)e^{-\frac12 (x+1)^2}\Big) = ce^{-\frac12(x+1)^2}.$$

From here you can find the solution using the $\Phi$ function (integral of that thing used in probability for the Gaussian distribution).

Comment: And that's probably the best you can do.